# Un-Zipping a file using GPG in android

Tags: android, unzip, gnupg

In my project i am going to un-zip the file which is in the SD-Card.

But the files are zipped using a client certificate to ensure that they zip cannot be unzipped on a device that is not authorized to see files.  So, using gpg we use
gpg-zip with client certificate on our side to create zip file -- the client
certificate is installed on device so gpg-unzip should be able to only unzip
if it has correct certificate. "

So, I have to un-zip the file using GPG.

Is it possible ? and how ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you solved it?? Can you give some idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to work for it. There is an open source library called Bouncy Castle which, among other things, can provide GPG decryption on Android.

Here's another related question: [Is there a good GnuPG encryption library for Java/Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455037/is-there-a-good-gnupg-encryption-library-for-java-scala)

Here's the Bouncy Castle homepage: http://www.bouncycastle.org/

And here's an example of it in use: http://code.google.com/p/android-privacy-guard/source/browse/src/org/thialfihar/android/apg/Apg.java