# How to encrypt a file using PGP encryption in jruby9.1.2.0?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am trying to encrypt file using gpg encryption before sending it in my jruby project. However I did not find adequate resources for it. I tried using [ruby-gpgme](https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme) but jruby did not support C libraries. I tried reading [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/index.html) but I was overwhelmed by the class documentation and did not find a simple article for encrypting a file.

Vivek's answern in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455037/is-there-a-good-gnupg-encryption-library-for-java-scala) question comes close to my solution, but there is only solution for decrypting the file. I am currently following [this article](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/05/13/revisited-pgp-encryptiondecryption-in-java/) and trying to interface the java code in jruby to no avail. I think the `encryptFile` function is what I need which is as follows:

```
public static void encryptFile(
        OutputStream out,
        String fileName,
        PGPPublicKey encKey,
        boolean armor,
        boolean withIntegrityCheck)
        throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        if (armor) {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP);

        PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(
                comData.open(bOut),
                PGPLiteralData.BINARY,
                new File(fileName) );

        comData.close();

        BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder dataEncryptor = new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.TRIPLE_DES);
        dataEncryptor.setWithIntegrityPacket(withIntegrityCheck);
        dataEncryptor.setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(dataEncryptor);
        encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey));

        byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
        OutputStream cOut = encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, bytes.length);
        cOut.write(bytes);
        cOut.close();
        out.close();
    }

)
```

I am getting following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `ZIP' for Java::OrgBouncycastleOpenpgp::PGPCompressedData:Class
```

at

```
 PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP);
```

It would be a great help if you can help me with the code or with the encrypting file using gpg in jruby as a whole.

**Update 1**
The ZIP value turns out to be constant of integer value and is listed in [this](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/constant-values.html#org.bouncycastle.bcpg.CompressionAlgorithmTags.ZIP) page.

**Update 2**
I made it till the function:

```
PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(dataEncryptor);
    encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey)); // encKey is class PGPPublicKey's instance
```

I have public key generated from OS. How do I create a PGPPublic Key instance `encKey`from the public key string I have?

Comment: `ZIP` may be a class constant rather than a method. try using `PGPCompressedData::ZIP` to reference a class constant rather than a `.ZIP` to reference a class method.

Comment: yeah, I found the respective constant value of the zip from this page. https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/constant-values.html#org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData.BINARY

Comment: i'm still trying to write a wrapper around it just for the encryption. help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, in Ruby `PGPCompressedData.zip` would call a method. You want to reference a constant inside the class. Using `::` rather than `.` should do the trick.

Reflecting on `PGPCompressedData` with `PGPCompressedData.constants.sort` and `PGPCompressedData.methods.sort` may also help.

Replacing `PGPCompressedData.ZIP` with `PGPCompressedData::ZIP` should do it if it is a constant.

Comment: @EnabrenTane I just passed the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find enough answer or gem to do it including the pgp library in the project folder. So I have forked [this repo](https://github.com/gmcmillan/gpgr) to [this repo](https://github.com/pravinbashyal/gpgr) to interface rails and the system's gpg library. It works on ubuntu. I have not tested it on other machines.

### Encryption:

In the machine with the public key installed

```
encryptObj = Gpgr::Encrypt::GpgFileForEncryption.new
encryptObj.email_address = <email_of_gpg_owner>
encryptObj.file = <path_to_file_to_encrypt>
encryptObj.file_output = <path_to_output_file>
encryptObj.encrypt
```

### Decryption

In the machine with the private key

```
decryptObj = Gpgr::Decrypt::GpgFileForDecryption.new
decryptObj.file = <path_to_file_to_decrypt>
decryptObj.file_output = <path_to_output_file>
decryptObj.decrypt
```